# jQuery variable based on live media query

Tags: jquery, variables, navigation, live, media-queries

I am creating a website that will have a responsive design based on CSS3 media queries (`lessframework`). 
The navigation I am using shows dropdown menus on hover but when the screen is resized and it goes into iPad or mobile view I need the navigation to change to `onclick`, at the moment this works after refreshing the page but not as soon as you resize the page.

What I need is for the code to change with a `.live()` or something so the page doesnt have to be refreshed when the window is resized.

Here's the code:

```
if ($('body').css('width') === '992px') {
    $('#nav li').hover(function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul.sub', this).stop().slideDown(100);
    }, function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul.sub', this).stop().slideUp(100);
    });
    //sub sub menu
    $('#nav ul li').hover(function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);

    }, function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);
    });
} else {

    $("ul.sub2>li").click(function () {

        return false;
    });
    $("ul.sub>li").click(function () {

        return false;
    });
    $("ul.sub>li:has(ul.sub2)").click(function () {

        $('.sub2').slideUp();
        $("ul.sub2", this).slideDown();
        return false;
    });

    $("ul#nav>li:has(ul.sub)").click(function () {
        $('.sub').slideUp();
        $('.sub2').slideUp();
        $("ul.sub", this).slideDown();
    });


}
});
```

Comment: rather than this `if ($('body').css('width') === '992px') {` you should probably use `$(window).width()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Resize is the jquery event that you shall listen for on the window object to be able to do things when the window size changes. For example you could have a variable store if the width is "ipad width or not" which you updates on window resize.

```
var ipad_width = $(window).width() < 992; //ipad_width => true || false

$(window).on('resize', function () {
     ipad_width = $(window).width() < 992
});
```

To avoid to bind more and more events every time you resize the browser i think an easy solution would be to bind all events from the start and have an if statement inside the bound functions that should just be executed in either ipad view or not in ipad view.
As an example:

```
$("ul.sub2>li").click(function () {
    if (ipad_width) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

And:

```
$('#nav li').hover(function () {
    if (!ipad_width) {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul.sub', this).stop().slideDown(100);
    }
}, function () {
    if (!ipad_width) {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul.sub', this).stop().slideUp(100);
    }
});
```